# How can I transform my input data to fit my desired Pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

Suppose I have the following input data regarding a pet owner.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

petowner1 = SimpleNamespace(
    id = 1,
    cats = [
            SimpleNamespace(id=1, name='Princess Peach')
        ],
    dogs = [
        SimpleNamespace(id=1, name='Sparky'),
        SimpleNamespace(id=2, name='Clifford')
    ]
)
```

`petowner1` has an `id`, a list of `cats`, and a list of `dogs`. ...but I think it makes more sense for an *Owner* to have a list of *Pets*, each with a `type` attribute ('cat' or 'dog'). Hence, I set up the following Pydantic models

```
class Pet(BaseModel):
    id: int
    type: str
    name: str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        

class Owner(BaseModel):
    id: int
    pets: List[Pet]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Given my input data, how can I populate these Pydantic models? My end goal is to do something like

```
owner = Owner.from_orm(petowner1)
owner.json()
```

which should output

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'pets': [
        {'id': 1, 'type': 'cat', 'name': 'Princess Peach'},
        {'id': 1, 'type': 'dog', 'name': 'Sparky'},
        {'id': 2, 'type': 'dog', 'name': 'Clifford'}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple loop to contruct object:

```
class Owner(BaseModel):
    id: int
    pets: List[Pet]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    @classmethod
    def from_orm(cls, p):
        pets = [
            *[Pet(id=cat.id, type="cat", name=cat.name) for cat in p.cats],
            *[Pet(id=dog.id, type="dog", name=dog.name) for dog in p.dogs],
        ]
        return cls(id=p.id, pets=pets)
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you're overriding BaseModel's [`from_orm()`](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/c532e8324e0a68fcecb239b02d66b55df7d9c684/pydantic/main.py#L554) method, yes? If so, isn't there a lot of *stuff* you're removing that `from_orm()` does, such as checking for `orm_mode` and calling `validate_model(cls, obj)`? Overriding `from_orm()` seems like a dangerous idea.

Comment: If you look into pydantic source code you can see that `__init__` and `from_orm` looks almost identical, the difference is `from_orm` calls `__new__` by itself. You have the same validation while constructing object so there is no danger at all.

Comment: Interesting. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out a solution that involves subclassing `GetterDict` and extending its `get()` method, as described [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#data-binding).

```
from typing import Optional, List, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.utils import GetterDict

class Pet(BaseModel):
    id: int
    pet_type: str
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class OwnerGetter(GetterDict):

    def get(self, key: str, default: Any = None) -> Any:
        if key == 'pets':
            pets = [
                *[Pet(pet_type="cat", id=x.id, name=x.name) for x in self._obj.cats],
                *[Pet(pet_type="cat", id=x.id, name=x.name) for x in self._obj.dogs],
            ]
            return pets

        else:
            return super(OwnerGetter, self).get(key, default)


class Owner(BaseModel):
    id: int
    pets: List[Pet]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        getter_dict = OwnerGetter
```

### Usage

```
owner = Owner.from_orm(petowner1)
owner.json()

{
  "id": 1,
  "pets": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "pet_type": "cat",
      "name": "Princess Peach"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "pet_type": "cat",
      "name": "Sparky"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "pet_type": "cat",
      "name": "Clifford"
    }
  ]
}
```

The caveat here is that we have to initialize each `Pet` using `Pet(pet_type="cat", id=x.id, name=x.name)` instead of `Pet.from_orm(...)`. I've created a lengthier version of this with a custom `PetGetter` so that I can use

```
pets = [
  *[Pet.from_orm(SimpleNamespace(pet_type="cat", data=x)) for x in self._obj.cats],
  *[Pet.from_orm(SimpleNamespace(pet_type="dog", data=x)) for x in self._obj.dogs]
]
```

in place of

```
pets = [
  *[Pet(pet_type="cat", id=x.id, name=x.name) for x in self._obj.cats],
  *[Pet(pet_type="cat", id=x.id, name=x.name) for x in self._obj.dogs]
]
```