# How to transform data for Pydantic Models?

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm trying to figure out how to validate **and** transform data within a Pydantic model. I'm retrieving data from an api on jobs (dummy example below) and need to map the fields to a Pydantic model. The json is converted to a Python dictionary first.

The problem is that the keys in the dictionary are different from the names of the model fields. I also need to apply some transformations to get the data in the format I want. In all the examples I found in the Pydantic documentation where a model is created from a different object (such as an `ORM` object), the fields are identical in name.

Like [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances) (`orm-mode`).

Originally, I used a helper function to map the dictionary keys to the model fields, but I was asked to perform the transformation when instantiating the model. I can't figure out how to pass the dictionary (or its keys) as an argument to the model, map the keys to the model fields, *and* validate the data.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, condecimal
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional


# example data
job_data = {
  'id': 10,
  'address': {
    'city': 'Brooklyn', 
    'state': 'New York'
  }, 
  'durationWeeks': 1.0, 
  'hoursPerWeek': 34.0, 
  'publicDescription': 'This is a public description', 
  'salary': 0.0, 
  'startDate': 1640581200000, 
  'title': 'Physician'
}

class Location(BaseModel):
  city: str
  state: str

class JobModel(BaseModel):
  id: int  # I'm aware this is a built-in function in Python
  location: Location
  duration: Optional[int] = None
  hours_per_week: Optional[int] = None
  description: str
  pay: Optional[condecimal(ge=0, decimal_places=2)] = None,
  start_date: datetime
  title: str

# Mapping:
# id -> id
# location -> address
# duration -> durationWeeks
# hours_per_week -> hoursPerWeek
# description -> publicDescription
# pay -> salary
# start_date -> from_timestamp(startDate)  # function to convert to a date object
# title -> title
```

What can I do? Defining `__init__` and passing the object as `JobModel(job_data)` raises an exception because the arguments don't match. And if I just set `__init__(job_data: Dict)` I can't set the fields I need. Will I need to map the job data as I declare an instance of the model?

I know there's also `Field(alias='new_name')` (example [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#reserved-names)) that I could use as a workaround, but is this the best approach?

Then there's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441329/how-can-i-transform-my-input-data-to-fit-my-desired-pydantic-model) showing examples with `GetterDict` and `from_orm`.

Which approach requires the least code?

Answer (score 3):

The best approach probably depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Since you wrote that you are getting data from an API, I would assume that you are ingesting them as JSON.

I don't know of any downsides to using aliases in a case like that. Just be aware of the different ways you can alias fields, and that they have a precedence (as described e.g. [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#alias-precedence)).

Regarding the conversion from timestamp to datetime: According to Pydantic's [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/#example):

> pydantic will process either a unix timestamp int (e.g. 1496498400) or a string representing the date & time.

In other words, when you use a `datetime` as the field type, "I should just work".

Below is how I would approach it with data coming from an API (as JSON). I dropped `location` and `description` as they are not in the `job_data`, and added the `Config` with field alias definitions:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, condecimal
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

job_data = {
  'id': 10,
  'address': {
    'city': 'Brooklyn', 
    'state': 'New York'
  }, 
  'durationWeeks': 1.0, 
  'hoursPerWeek': 34.0, 
  'publicDescription': 'This is a public description', 
  'salary': 0.0, 
  'startDate': 1640581200000, 
  'title': 'Physician'
}

class JobModel(BaseModel):
  id: int
  duration: Optional[int] = None
  hours_per_week: Optional[int] = None
  pay: Optional[condecimal(ge=0, decimal_places=2)] = None,
  start_date: datetime
  title: str

  class Config:
      fields = {'start_date': 'startDate'}

## parse_obj is DEPRECATED
# jd = JobModel.parse_obj(job_data)
jd = JobModel.model_validate(job_data)

print(jd)
# id=10 
# duration=None 
# hours_per_week=None 
# pay=(None,) 
# start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 27, 5, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# title='Physician'
```

The [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_validate):

The behavior is the same as the deprecated `parse_obj`.

> `parse_obj`: this is very similar to the `__init__` method of the model, except it takes a dict rather than keyword arguments. If the object passed is not a dict a `ValidationError` will be raised.

There is also a `model_validate_json` for use as well.

This should make it a bit safer and you could add a `try`-`except` block (catching `ValidationError`) around it, if you wanted to make it fool-proof.

However, you might as well initialise the model directly, the result will be the same:

```py
jd = JobModel(**job_data)

print(jd)
# id=10 
# duration=None 
# hours_per_week=None
# pay=(None,) 
# start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 27, 5, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# title='Physician'
```